# Crashplan not starting. Fails to find swt-gtk

Tags: kde, crashplan

I've installed Crashplan on my (K)Ubuntu computer. However, it fails to start and the ui_output.log says:

```
[09.02.12 15:24:43.518 INFO    main                 root                                    ] *************************************************************
[09.02.12 15:24:43.519 INFO    main                 root                                    ] *************************************************************
[09.02.12 15:24:43.524 INFO    main                 root                                    ] Loading lib/swt-64.jar, exists=true
[09.02.12 15:24:43.525 INFO    main                 root                                    ] [file:/usr/local/crashplan/lib/com.backup42.desktop.jar, file:/usr/local/crashplan/lang/, file:/usr/local/crashplan/skin/, file:/usr/local/crashplan/lib/swt-64.jar]
[09.02.12 15:24:43.527 INFO    main                 root                                    ] STARTED CrashPlanDesktop
[09.02.12 15:24:43.528 INFO    main                 root                                    ] CPVERSION = 3.2.1 - 1332824401321 (2012-03-27T05:00:01:321+0000)
[09.02.12 15:24:43.529 INFO    main                 root                                    ] ARGS = [  ]
[09.02.12 15:24:43.531 INFO    main                 root                                    ] LOCALE = English (United States)
[09.02.12 15:24:43.570 ERROR   main                 com.backup42.desktop.CPDesktop          ] Failed to launch CPDesktop; java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3557 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3557 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3557 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.backup42.desktop.CPDesktop.<init>(CPDesktop.java:231)
    at com.backup42.desktop.CPDesktop.main(CPDesktop.java:161)

[09.02.12 15:24:43.570 ERROR   main                 root                                    ] Failed to launch CPDesktop;  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3557 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
```

I've installed the relevant (I think) swt-gtk packages.

Comment: CrashPlan is a paid service with their own tech support staff, have you contacted them for advice? You might try that if you don't get a good answer here. Also, your issue is similar to [this one dating back to 2009](http://kember.net/articles?page=2), which relates to Java. Have you made any changes to your Java install recently? There are many [security issues and updates](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/08/critical-bug-discovered-in-newest-java/) recently, maybe that's related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when I reinstalled CrashPlan after moving onto an SSD. I had moved `/tmp` to RAM, and set restrictive permissions on the folder in my `/etc/fstab`.

This was causing my problem:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,mode=1777 0 0
```

This fixed it:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

The `noexec` parameter prevents SWT from executing from the `/tmp` directory, removing it fixes the problem.

Comment: You sir are a genius.  I've been fighting to get rid of the stupid swt-gtk error with crashplan for a few months.  I was actually resorting to running a remote GUI from windows in virtualbox.  This one change to my /etc/fstab fixed it.  Thank you for sharing this solution.