# CrashPlan app not launching

Tags: java, gtk, crashplan

it is a very similar problem to that described here:

[Crashplan not starting. Fails to find swt-gtk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183256/crashplan-not-starting-fails-to-find-swt-gtk)

However I have not succeded at resolving this issue. The error I get in  `/usr/local/crashplan/log/ui_output.log` after I launch the CrashPlanDesktop command to run the GUI for crashplan is the following

```
[01.15.14 15:46:41.556 ERROR main root ] Failed to launch CPDesktop; java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: Can't load library: /tmp/.cpswt/libswt-gtk-4234.so Can't load library: /tmp/.cpswt/libswt-gtk.so no swt-gtk-4234 in java.library.path no swt-gtk in java.library.path /tmp/.cpswt/libswt-gtk-4234.so: /tmp/.cpswt/libswt-gtk-4234.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

The output of `locate swt-gtk` is:

```
/usr/lib/java/swt-gtk-3.7.2.jar
/usr/lib/jni/libswt-gtk-3740.so
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-java
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-jni
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-java/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-java/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-java/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-java/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-jni/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libswt-gtk-3-jni/copyright
/usr/share/java/swt-gtk-3.7.jar
/usr/share/java-config/libswt-gtk-3-java
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libswt-gtk-3-java
/var/cache/apt/archives/libswt-gtk-3-java_3.7.2-2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libswt-gtk-3-jni_3.7.2-2_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libswt-gtk-3-java.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libswt-gtk-3-java.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libswt-gtk-3-java.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libswt-gtk-3-java.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libswt-gtk-3-jni.list
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this post: https://forums.amahi.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=4951

Following that advice, I fixed the problem by downloading both the x86 *and* x86-64 jars of SWT for Linux/GTK2 from here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/#SWT

You need to extract each jar into a temporary location:
unzip foo.jar

Go into crashplan/lib and move the existing swt.jar and swt-64.jar files aside so you can put them back if this doesn't help.

Copy the swt.jar from the x86 jar into crashplan/lib as swt.jar

Copy the swt.jar from the x86-64 jar into crashplan/lib as swt-64.jar

With luck CrashPlanDesktop will then start OK. I don't know why this is necessary or whose fault it is that it broke, but it did work for me!